# Saving contact form 7 data into custom db on specific contact form

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

```
function contactform7_before_send_mail( $form_to_DB ) {
//set your db details
$mydb = new wpdb('newsletter','newsletter','newsletter','localhost');
$form_to_DB = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
if ( $form_to_DB ) 
    $formData = $form_to_DB->get_posted_data();
$title = $formData['name'];
$email = $formData['email'];

$mydb->insert( 'newsletter', array( 'name' =>$title, 'email' =>  $email ), array( '%s' ) );

remove_all_filters ('wpcf7_before_send_mail');
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'contactform7_before_send_mail' );
```

Can know how to apply this code to one specific contact form only.

It means. I have few forms from contact form 7. but I only need to save data from, 1 form only.

Answer (score 0):

The `wpcf7_before_send_mail` hook passes three arguments.

`$contact_form, &$abort, $submission`

You want to use the property `$contact_form->id`.

```php
function contactform7_before_send_mail($form_to_DB) {
    if ($form_to_DB->id === 123) {// Your Form ID
        $mydb = new wpdb( 'newsletter', 'newsletter', 'newsletter', 'localhost' );
        $form_to_DB = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        if ( $form_to_DB )
            $formData = $form_to_DB->get_posted_data();
        $title = $formData['name'];
        $email = $formData['email'];

        $mydb->insert( 'newsletter', array( 'name' => $title, 'email' => $email ), array( '%s' ) );

        remove_all_filters( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'contactform7_before_send_mail' );
```